# How to generate multiple card for each object in an array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, dynamically-generated

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "fanwood";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url("fonts/Fanwood.otf");
    font-display: swap;
}

:root {
    --color-primary: #e9e2d7;
    --color-primary-alt: #8e6549;
    --color-secondary: #d42257;
    --color-background: #d2fbf7;
    --color-text: #412d86;
    --color-light: #fff;
    --color-anchor: #3a00ff;
    --font-family: "fanwoood";
    --font-weight-strong: 500;
    --font-size-h1: 4rem;
    --font-size-h2: 3rem;
    --font-size-h3: 2rem;
    --font-size-h4: 1.35rem;
    --font-size-text: 1.15rem;
    --border-radius: 8px;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Remove default margin */

body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    margin: 0;
}

html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}


/* Set core body defaults */

body {
    font-family: 'fanwood';
    min-height: 100vh;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}


/* Make images easier to work with */

img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}


/* Inherit fonts for inputs and buttons */

input,
button,
textarea,
select {
    font: inherit;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--color-primary);
}

button {
    background-color: var(--color-primary);
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
}

input {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px 0;
}

.site-wrapper {
    margin: 0 4%;
}

.card-info-wrapper {
    margin: 4% 4%;
}

.header {
    color: var(--color-primary);
    background-color: var(--color-primary-alt);
    height: 84px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.tool-bar {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.tools {
    display: flex;
}

.button {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    color: var(--color-primary-alt);
    background-color: var(--color-primary);
}

.button.add {
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    background-color: var(--color-primary-alt);
    color: var(--color-primary);
}

.books-wrapper {
    margin-top: 20px;
    /* border: 1px solid white; */
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.book-card {
    word-wrap: normal;
    background-color: var(--color-primary-alt);
    color: var(--color-primary);
    width: 300px;
    height: 350px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.form-card {
    display: none;
    word-wrap: normal;
    background-color: var(--color-primary-alt);
    color: var(--color-primary);
    width: 300px;
    height: 350px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.toggle-on {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Book</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="header">
        <div class="site-wrapper">
            <div class="header-logo-container">
                <h1>Library</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tool-bar">
        <div class="site-wrapper">
            <div class="tools">
                <div class="button add" id="add-form">
                    Add Book
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="books">
        <div class="site-wrapper">
            <div class="books-wrapper">
                <!-- TEMPLATE FOR BOOK CARD -->
                <!-- <div class="book-card"> 
                    <div class="card-info-wrapper">
                        <h2>Title</h2>
                        <h3>Author</h3>
                        <h4>Pages</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum fugit officiis animi soluta et, sit aliquid.</p>
                        <div class="button">
                            Remove
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> -->
                <div class="form-card">
                    <div class="card-info-wrapper">
                        <form id="input-form">
                            <label for="title"><h3>Title</h3></label>
                            <input type="text" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Name of the Book" required>

                            <label for="author"><h3>Author</h3></label>
                            <input type="text" id="author" name="author" placeholder="Name of the Author" required>

                            <label for="pages"><h3>Pages</h3></label>
                            <input type="number" id="pages" name="pages" placeholder="Number of Pages" required>

                            <button type="submit" class="button" id="addBook">Add Book</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to generate multiple cards for every object in an array. The issue i am facing is that every time a new object gets added a duplicate card of the existing object in the array is being generated. Is there some way to fix it just by using vanilla js?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsApw.png

```js
const form = document.getElementById('input-form');
const formButton = document.getElementById('add-form');
const formView = document.querySelector('.form-card')
const bookList = document.querySelector('.books-wrapper');
const bookCard = document.querySelector('.book-card');

let myLibrary = [];
let newBook;

function Book(title, author, pages) {
  this.title = title;
  this.author = author;
  this.pages = pages;
  this.info = function() {
    return `${this.title} is a book by ${this.author}, ${this.pages} pages, not read yet.`
  };
};
Book.prototype.read = false;

function addToLibrary(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const title = (document.getElementById('title')).value;
  const author = (document.getElementById('author')).value;
  const pages = (document.getElementById('pages')).value;
  newBook = new Book(title, author, pages);

  myLibrary.push(newBook);
  populateBooks(myLibrary, bookList);
  formDisplay();
  this.reset();
  console.table(myLibrary)
};

function populateBooks(myLib, bookView) {
  myLib.forEach((book, i) => {
    const card = `<div class="book-card" data-index=${i}>
                            <div class="card-info-wrapper">
                                 <h2>${book.title}</h2>
                                 <h3>${book.author}</h3>
                                 <h4>${book.pages} Pages</h4>
                                 <p>${book.info()}</p>
                                     <div class="button">
                                        Remove
                                     </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>`
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    element.innerHTML = card;
    bookView.appendChild(element.firstChild);

  });

};
function formDisplay() {
formView.classList.toggle('toggle-on');
};
formButton.addEventListener('click', formDisplay);
populateBooks(myLibrary, bookList);
[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're appending your entire library of books again to an already populated div.

Your solution is simple, just clean your div of books before appending everything again.

Here is your JS modified and working:

```
const form = document.getElementById('input-form');
const formButton = document.getElementById('add-form');
const formView = document.querySelector('.form-card')
const bookList = document.querySelector('.books-wrapper');
const bookCard = document.querySelector('.book-card');

let myLibrary = [];
let newBook;

function Book(title, author, pages) {
  this.title = title;
  this.author = author;
  this.pages = pages;
  this.info = function() {
    return `${this.title} is a book by ${this.author}, ${this.pages} pages, not read yet.`
  };
};
Book.prototype.read = false;

function addToLibrary(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const title = (document.getElementById('title')).value;
  const author = (document.getElementById('author')).value;
  const pages = (document.getElementById('pages')).value;
  newBook = new Book(title, author, pages);

  myLibrary.push(newBook);
  populateBooks(myLibrary, bookList);
  formDisplay();
  this.reset();
  console.table(myLibrary)
};

function populateBooks(myLib, bookView) {
  bookList.innerHTML = "";
  myLib.forEach((book, i) => {
    const card = `<div class="book-card" data-index=${i}>
                            <div class="card-info-wrapper">
                                 <h2>${book.title}</h2>
                                 <h3>${book.author}</h3>
                                 <h4>${book.pages} Pages</h4>
                                 <p>${book.info()}</p>
                                     <div class="button">
                                        Remove
                                     </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>`
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    element.innerHTML = card;
    bookView.appendChild(element.firstChild);

  });

}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
        addToLibrary(e)
    });
});
```

I modified some parts in order to make it work locally since you didn't posted your HTML.

The line I added was:

```
bookList.innerHTML = "";
```

Right at the start of your `populateBooks` function.

Edit: Got it working with the updated code, [Here is the JSFiddle with your full code modified to working.](https://jsfiddle.net/9380t5p7/)

The thing was adding the command `document.querySelectorAll('.book-card').forEach(e => e.remove());` to remove all the already-rendered books inside your div, so then when you run your function, it would delete just the books and then render it all again properly.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand what is happening, but when i added that line, the form is not working for some reason, ill add the html code. Also is this the right way to go about this? is there any other way i can do the same thing?

Comment: Deleted my other comment. I was mistaken now seeing your full code. The code needed for it to work was to remove all the book-card divs before your function that rendered the other books. [Here is a JS fiddle with all your code now fully working](https://jsfiddle.net/9380t5p7/)

Comment: I also updated my answer to reflect the actual solution.

Comment: Thank you, its working fine now. I still have a question, is the right way to implement the this or is it just some quick fix to a bad code? This project is in the curriculum of TOP, and most of the other students sol is creating dom elements with js which got me wondering if this the right way to implement this function.

Comment: There is essentially no "right" or "wrong" way on working with DOM elements. There's just a way that facilitates your interaction, and others that may make it difficult to maintain it in the future. Creating DOM elements manually in JS is recommended since its easier to modify and work with it in case you need to implement new features to your app. But your way it is certainly not "wrong".